# Why is there no symmetric difference for collections.Counter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, counter

So for sets you can do a symmetric difference (^) which is the equivalent of union minus intersection. Why is ^ an unsupported operand for Counter objects while union and intersection still work?

Comment: There's no definitive answer to be had.  "The usual" answer to questions like this is that, at the time the module was designed, nobody cared enough about this particular case to do the work of implementing it - and neither did anyone care enough about it later, either ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, turns out it was discussed at time, and rejected.

Click the link for the full message (and its thread); I'll just quote the "high order bits" of Raymond Hettinger's reply:

> It's unlikely that I will add this [symmetric difference] method to the Counter API because
>   the rarity of use case does not warrant the added API complexity.
>   IMO, adding a method like this makes the class harder to learn,
>   understand and remember.  It doesn't seem like much of a win over
>   using the existing alternatives:
>
> ...
>
> I would like to see someone post a subclass to the ASPN Cookbook that
>   adds a number of interesting, though not common operations.
>
> ...
>
> The Counter() class has low aspirations.  It is a dictionary that
>   fills-in missing values with zero and is augmented by a handful of
>   basic methods for managing the counts.

Full message here:

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-August/585040.html

There's also a recipe in the ASPN Cookbook implementing `__xor__` in a `Counter` subclass:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577362-extension-to-python-3-counter-class/

Comment: First link seems wrong, but I found it here now: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-August/735420.html

Answer (score 2):

For Counter objects, `&` and `|` don't mean intersection and union as they do for sets ... they mean `max` and `min`.

> Several mathematical operations are provided for combining Counter objects to produce multisets (counters that have counts greater than zero). Addition and subtraction combine counters by adding or subtracting the counts of corresponding elements. Intersection and union return the minimum and maximum of corresponding counts. Each operation can accept inputs with signed counts, but the output will exclude results with counts of zero or less.

With these definitions, what would the `^` operator mean?

If you want the symmetric difference of the keys, you can do [`c1.viewkeys() ^ c2.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) <sup>1</sup>

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>on python3.x, use `.keys()` instead</sup>

Comment: "^" would mean the max minus the min, which reduces to the plain-old-set operation if the only possible multiplicities are 0 and 1.  That's conventional, but I've very rarely seen it used for multisets.  Here's one reference in agreement:  https://oeis.org/wiki/Multisets#Generalized_set_operations

Comment: @TimPeters -- Cool.  Tell Raymond to get on that ;-).  In any event, I'm pretty sure that isn't what OP actually wants here ...

Comment: Raymond won't be interested ;-)  But I'd bet the OP did have that in mind, given that they wrote "is the equivalent of union minus intersection".  In that sense, symmetric difference is defined the same way for multisets and plain-old-sets.