# Find number of unique char to be dropped from string to get Anagram using Python

Tags: python, string, data-structures, substring, anagram

Alice is taking a cryptography class and finding anagrams to be very useful. We consider two strings to be anagrams of each other if the first string's letters can be rearranged to form the second string. In other words, both strings must contain the same exact letters in the same exact frequency For example, bacdc and dcbac are anagrams, but bacdc and dcbad are not.

Alice decides on an encryption scheme involving two large strings where encryption is dependent on the minimum number of character deletions required to make the two strings anagrams. Can you help her find this number?

Given two strings, a and b, that may or may not be of the same length, determine the minimum number of character deletions required to make a and b anagrams. Any characters can be deleted from either of the strings.

For example, if a=cde and b=dcf, we can delete e from string a and f from string b so that both remaining strings are cd and dc which are anagrams.

The code I tried.

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
from collections import Counter 

# Complete the makeAnagram function below.

def makeAnagram(str1, str2):
   new= str1 + str2
   unique =[]
   z=0
   for char in new[:]:
       a = new.count(char)
       if a%2!=0 and char not in unique:
           z=z+(a%2)
           unique.append(char)
       a=0
   return z
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    a = input()

    b = input()

    res = makeAnagram(a, b)

    fptr.write(str(res) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

For Input

fcrxzwscanmligyxyvym

jxwtrhvujlmrpdoqbisbwhmgpmeoke

My output is 14

As per the answers given, the output should be 30.

Comment: What is the point of assigning `a=0` at the bottom of the loop?  It immediately gets reassigned at the top of the loop anyway.

Comment: The question has some odd sentences like `For example, if and , we can delete from string and from string so that both remaining strings are and which are anagrams.` What is going on?

Comment: What is your specific question?  What output are you getting, and how is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The function seems to work. I'm not familiar with the way you are writing to the file try using this instead:

```
fptr = open("MyFile.txt","w")
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is the symmetric difference between two counters. Which can be computed more efficiently directly, but via the interface of Counter, it can be expressed as `(x - y) + (y - x)`.

```
a = "fcrxzwscanmligyxyvym"
b = "jxwtrhvujlmrpdoqbisbwhmgpmeoke"

from collections import Counter

x = Counter(a)
y = Counter(b)

sum(((x - y) + (y - x)).itervalues()) # => 30
```

For why the Counter class doesn't have this as a method see [Why is there no symmetric difference for collections.Counter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449289/why-is-there-no-symmetric-difference-for-collections-counter)